# No consigo poner bien la ruta a los archivos .css

Tags: html5, css3

Tengo la siguiente estructura de un proyecto.[image: pantallazo rutas]

Y no consigo que me carguen los estilos css. Si `header.php` esta dentro de includes y los archivos CSS dentro de css por que no me funciona `../css/style.css`?

¿Qué ruta tengo que poner?

/css/bootstrap.css

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tienes un problema de rutas. Si te fijas la que usas para la imagen **logo5.png** es **images/logo5.png** pero los .css lo estas poniendo al mismo nivel del directorio de las imagenes. Solo quita ../ de la ruta **../css/bootstrap.css** y que quede solamente **css/bootstrap.css** y eso funcionara.

Probablemente estes usando un **include('includes/header.php')** dentro de tu archivo **index.php** y por eso la ruta de la imagen es correcta y la de tus css es incorrecta ya que al incluir el markup de **header.php** dentro del **index.php** con la funcion **include()** estas poniendo lo que está en **header.php** dentro del nivel de **index.php**

**EDITADO**
En el caso de seguir teniendo el error la siguiente causa probable sería los privilegios de acceso al archivo. Recomiendo asignar los permisos correspondientes (dependiendo de tu Sistema Operativo) de lectura para poder descartar el error.

Comment: ya he probado css/bootstrap.css y no funciona

Comment: Las rutas dejalas como te sugiero, ahora prueba con los permisos de los archivos. Probablemente no tengan permisos de visualización, o la carpeta o los archivos. Si usar windows puedes darle clic derecho a la carpeta, luego Opciones de Carpeta, pestaña Privilegios (si no mal recuerdo) y habilita los permisos de lectura y escritura del archivo. 
<br><br>
Si usas Chrome o Firefox puedes abrir la consola y ver los errores que te marca, ahí si dejas las rutas que te recomiendo debes ver el error de permiso, esos son las posibles causas de tu error, las rutas o los permisos

Comment: tenias razon eran los permisos, uso ubuntu...

Comment: Hola @crlsmtzprds. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so] y gracias por contribuir +1! Sería genial si pudieses [edit] la respuesta para agregar la parte de permisos y dejar una respuesta aún más completa.